# What is this picture about in Mirai Nikki?

Tags: mirai-nikki

[image: Yuno and Yuki are creating a world together]

In the picture, Yuno and Yukki are creating a world together, but what's this about? I don't know if it is an episode from the anime or from the manga.

I'm still searching for it in the internet but can't find anything about it. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the OVA (["Redial"](https://myanimelist.net/anime/16762/Mirai_Nikki_Redial), which adapts a [2-chapter manga](https://myanimelist.net/manga/50205/Mirai_Nikki__Redial)), it'll make more sense. In brief:

> Yukiteru-2 has been deified in world #3. Yuno-3 is initially unaware that Yukiteru-2 exists, the whole Future Diary thing, etc., but Murmur-2 eventually transports her to Deus-3's metaphysical space where Murmur-2 is imprisoned, whereupon Murmur-2 imbues Yuno-3 with Yuno-2's memories. She then goes and finds the now-deified Yukiteru-2. The OVA ends with Yuno-3 and Yukiteru-2 meeting, but I imagine the implication is that they create a new world together afterwards, as at the end of episode 26.

Er, at least, I *think* I have all the world numbers right, but it's been a while.

Answer (score -1):

The image is in the anime at the end of the 26th episode after the credits roll. That is because Yukiteru is reunited with Yuno.